# r markdown - how to align tables to left rather than centre when knitting to PDF?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Would think this was simple to resolve?

In R markdown, when knitting to PDF, how do I get all tables to align left rather than centre?

Comment: Hello Alexa. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: It literally would have been quicker to type the answer, such a simple chunk of code. I worked it out, with many thanks to this great community, who only reply with how to format your questions rather than answer the question. Used to be good community on here when I started to code 12 years ago, now it's a waste of time.

Comment: I don't use R Markdown to PDF every day, so it was much easier to cut & paste the URL to [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) than it was to do the research to figure out how to left align R Markdown tables written to PDF, especially since the sources I used gave inconsistent guidance.

Comment: Isn't that the point of the forums? That you only need reply if you know, or can access the answers? Thank-you for looking into it.

Comment: You're welcome. There is a large community of people who use Stackoverflow to develop their own skills by answering other people's questions. I coach my team members and graduate level data scientists I mentor to spend time on Stack to develop their skills by answering questions. There is quite a bit of value to be gained by crafting a well articulated answer to a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to left align tables in R Markdown documents that are written to PDF is to use a combination of `format = latex` and `booktabs = TRUE` within the `kable()` function.

````
---
title: "Left Align Tables"
date: "2023-04-14"
output: 
     pdf_document:
         extra_dependencies: ["booktabs"]

---

```{r aTable}
library(knitr)
kable(head(mtcars[,1:5]),format = "latex",booktabs = TRUE)
```
````

This results in the following PDF content:

[image]

````
Try again without the options...

```{r aTable2}
library(knitr)
kable(head(mtcars[,1:5]),)
```
````

...which produces the following:

[image]

Note that I included the YAML pdf document dependency of "booktabs" per section 10.1.10 of the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#customize-latex-tables) for completeness, even though the code worked as desired without specifying the dependency in YAML.

### What happens when the table contains a caption?

Here's where the basic answer begins to get complicated. Why? Tables that include captions are managed in what LaTeX calls a table environment. Unfortunately the default alignment for tables within a LaTeX table environment is centered.

````
Things get more complicated when a table has a caption. 

```{r aTable3}
kable(head(mtcars[,1:5]),format = "latex",booktabs = TRUE,
      caption = "1973 - 1974 Cars from Motor Trend")
```
````

[image]

To left align the table with a caption, we need to add the `centering = TRUE` option to `kable()`.  Also note that LaTeX is now positioning the table at the bottom of the page, but managing the float on a LaTeX document is beyond the scope of this question.

````
```{r aTable4}
kable(head(mtcars[,1:5]),format = "latex",booktabs = TRUE,centering = FALSE,
      caption = "1973 - 1974 Cars from Motor Trend - Noncentered")
```
````

[image]

Arrgh! Now our table is left aligned, but the caption is centered. To fix the caption, we need to add another LaTeX package in the YAML, the `caption` package, add `header-includes` content to use the caption package and then use `kableExtra()` to reformat the caption.

A complete solution looks like this:

````
---
title: "Left Align Tables"
date: "2023-04-14"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["booktabs","caption"]
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) 
library(knitr)
```


Hmm... now the table is left aligned, but the caption is not. To left align the caption, we need to add some LaTeX header content in the YAML, and add the LaTeX caption package. Then we use kableExtra to format the caption. 

```{r aTable5}
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(mtcars[,1:5]),format = "latex",booktabs = TRUE,centering = FALSE,
      caption = "1973 - 1974 Cars from Motor Trend - Noncentered") %>%
     kable_styling(position = "left")
```
````

[image]

Voilà! We now have a left-aligned table with a left aligned caption. Code to manage the float (where the tables are placed on the page) is left as a trivial exercise for the reader.

Comment: @AlexaQuinoa - you're welcome. After posting my original answer, I added content to explain what is needed to left align the caption for a table in `knitr()`. It is clearly a non-trivial undertaking.

Comment: Thanks! I've just spent the last 3 hours trying to either align the caption left or remove the caption completely. However, removal using                       \usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} only removed the automatic headings knitted to tables and figures, and did not align my own headings left. So, you've pre-empted my next query. It is rather more complicated than I initially expected. Thank-you again Len, I have the tables of my dreams.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the kable.extra package:

```
df_df %>% 
   kbl(caption = " caption") %>% 
   kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), position = "left", full_width = FALSE, fixed_thead = T)
```